# MySql Indexes are not applied in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, search, group-by, myisam, large-data

I have two tables to make my search engine, one containing all keywords and the other contains all the possible targets for each keyword.

```
Table: keywords
id (int)
keyword (varchar)

Table: results
id (int)
keyword_id (int)
table_id (int)
target_id (int)
```

For both tables, I set *MyISAM* as storage engine since 95% of the times I am just running select queries on these tables and in 5% of the times, insert queries. And off course, I already compared the performance using InnoDB and the performance was poor considering my later queries.

I also added the following indexes

```
keywords.keyword (unique)
results.keyword_id (index)
results.table_id (index)
results.target_id (index)
```

in the *keywords* table, I have about 1.2 million records and in *results* table I have about 9.8 million records.

Now the **issue** is that I run the following query and the results is made in 0.0014 seconds

```
SELECT rs.table_id, rs.target_id
FROM keywords ky INNER JOIN results rs ON ky.id=rs.keyword_id
WHERE ky.keyword LIKE "x%" OR ky.keyword LIKE "y%"
```

But when I add GROUP BY, the result is made in 0.2 seconds

```
SELECT rs.table_id, rs.target_id
FROM keywords ky INNER JOIN results rs ON ky.id=rs.keyword_id
WHERE ky.keyword LIKE "x%" OR ky.keyword LIKE "y%"
GROUP BY rs.table_id, rs.target_id
```

I tested composite indexes, single column indexes and even dropping table_id and target_id indexes but in all the cases the performance is the same and it seems that in Group By clause, the index is not applied.

The explain plan shows that:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1 | SIMPLE | ky | range | PRIMARY,keyword | keyword | 767 | NULL | 3271 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE | rs | ref | keyword_id | keyword_id | 4 | ky.id | 3
```

I have the following composite key already added

```
ALTER TABLE results ADD INDEX `table_id` (`table_id`, `target_id`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: InnoDB is faster then MyISAM when the server is configurated correctly read https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/

Comment: I read the document, I couldn't find anything about the server config and according to what I understood, considering my application, MyISAM is faster.

Comment: In MyISAM, `keywords.keyword (unique)` is sub-optimal; with InnoDB it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) MySQL documentation for GROUP BY optimization, this is what it says:

> The most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are
>   that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index

So, if you have different index on these two columns, they won't be used by `GROUP BY`. You should try creating a composite index on `table_id` and `target_id`.

Also, the query seem to be using `LIKE` operator. Please note that if the value being compared in `LIKE` has leading wildcard in it then MySQL won't be able to use any index for that column anyway. Have a look at `explain plan` of the query and see which indices are used.

Comment: I tried composite key on table_id and target_id but it doesn't work. EXPLAIN plan also doesn't include the composite index. Moreover, considering the number of records and the query time, you may noticed that the index on keyword column is working fine. EXPLAIN plan also says that the index is being used.

Comment: Probably because of `LIKE` operator as I explained, have a look at the explain plan of the query.

Comment: This is what I get for keyword index: SIMPLE
ky
range
PRIMARY,keyword
keyword
767
NULL
3271
Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Does it show any other index? Can you add it into the question?

Comment: @MohammadAli From the explain plan, it looks like index is being used on  `keyword_id`. As MySQL can only use one index per table, `GROUP BY` index does not show up in the explain plan. I would try dropping the existing indices and adding a composite index on (`keyword_id`, `table_id` and `target_id`).

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` + `GROUP BY` (or `DISTINCT`) is what I call "explode-implode" -- First the `JOIN` multiplies the number of 'rows' to look at, then the `GROUP BY` deflates the row count.

One work around to avoid this is to focus on the primary table, then check for `EXISTS` in the other table:

```
SELECT  rs.table_id, rs.target_id
    FROM  keywords ky
    WHERE  EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
            FROM  results rs
            WHERE  ky.id = rs.keyword_id
              AND  ( ky.keyword LIKE "x%"
                 OR  ky.keyword LIKE "y%" )
                 );
```

`rs` requires `INDEX(keyword_id)`.

An improvement on that might be to get rid of the `OR` via

```
            WHERE  ky.id = rs.keyword_id
              AND  ky.keyword REGEXP "^[xy]"
```

But that is not very helpful since it still needs to fully check `keyword`.

Another improvement could be to turn the `OR` into `UNION`:

```
(  SELECT  rs.table_id, rs.target_id
        FROM  keywords ky
        INNER JOIN  results rs  ON ky.id=rs.keyword_id
        WHERE ky.keyword LIKE "x%"
) UNION ALL
(  SELECT  rs.table_id, rs.target_id
        FROM  keywords ky
        INNER JOIN  results rs  ON ky.id=rs.keyword_id
        WHERE ky.keyword LIKE "y%"
)

ky: INDEX(keyword, id)
rs: INDEX(keyword_id)
```

The advantage here (other than avoiding the inflate-deflate) is that the index can be used on.

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; there may be other tips.)